# How to run 2 different webview files in 1 activity that I use?

Tags: android, html, button, webview

I plan to run a hundred of html file that need html Webview. I run them directly. This is my code so far:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class Button1Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button1);

        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/e9.html");

    }

}
```

But when I ask one other activity with dedicated buttons to reach the same performance error occurs.
The code below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;


public class Button4Activity extends Activity {

    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.button4);


        Button b31 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonE1);
        b31.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
                web.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/e9.html");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: please post the error occured